# в массиве действительных чисел все нулевые элементы заменить на среднее арифметическое всех элементов массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

помогите с задачей ;3 
в массиве действительных чисел все нулевые элементы заменить на среднее арифметическое всех элементов массива

язык: python

Comment: В чем возникли трудности?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker не знаю как реализовать на питоне, не очень сильно знаком с ним, а задачу решить нужно ;(

Comment: Решение такой задачи "в лоб" не требует углубленных знаний питона. Да и учитесь вы не просто так, изучайте.

Comment: _s = reduce(lamda x,y: x+y, array) / len(array); map(..., array)_

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку не указан источник чисел, то генерируем N случайных на отрезке [-3;3]

```
import random as rand

n = int(input("n= "))

if n>0:
    lst=[-3+6*rand.random() for i in range(n)]
    print(lst)
    sr=sum(lst)/len(lst)
    for k,x in enumerate(lst):
        if x==0:
            lst[k]=sr
    print(lst)
```